# generate types from chain does not work. Documentation is not clear

Tags: parachain, javascript, typescript, custom-types

I dont think typegen is working as expected per documentation, by following the provided example and adapting it to my parachain.

`
Found 244 errors in 5 files.

Errors  Files
5  src/interfaces/augment-api-consts.ts:61
111  src/interfaces/augment-api-events.ts:67
59  src/interfaces/augment-api-query.ts:23
68  src/interfaces/augment-api-tx.ts:97
1  src/interfaces/index.ts:4
`

I see the following problems:

- types.js is empty
- definitions is empty
- the generated code is not finding generated types (there is no import statement) which seems like something is broken.
- no interfaces/module folders have been generated for my para-chain pallets, which I would expect

I think there is a gap between what we developers expect and what TypeGen does, but the documentation isn't clear about it.

I expect typegen to read my parachain metadata and fully gererate an interfaces folder so that all my custom types are defined just as they are when using the relay chain (Polkadot/Kusama). I expect activating this interfaces via a typescript mapping. I don't expect having to make choices about what gets or does not get generated.

I don't expect having to patch auto-generated code or touch the intefaces folders in general.

I think my expectations are wrong, but the documentation is not clear about what do you have to provide to generate all the types used by your parachain.

How does Typegen works?

Comment: per https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/issues/5503 it seems like typegen is actually broken. Would be nice to mention in the documentation at least that the functionality is experimental.

Comment: can anybody point me to a repo in which parachain types are generated and used with typegen?